# VBA, Internet Explorer and Javascript

Tags: jquery, excel, vba, internet-explorer, oracle-apex

I'm currently working on a VBA automatisation between Excel Files and Oracle Data base via APEX using Internet Explorer but the last Oracle update give me some issues.

(I'm still using internet explorer instead of another web browser because I can't install any external software on my computer at work.)

At one point my VBA code was suppose to "Click" on a button launching Java Script for Log in.
This is the HTML code I can read on my Internet Explorer Browser :
`<a href="javascript:apex.submit(%7Brequest:'LOGIN'%7D);">Connexion</a>`

Any advise or Ideas ?

With my VBA code, this is what I did

```
Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium                                                         
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate ("ToMyURL")
    Set idoc = ie.Document                                                                  
    Set ElementCol = idoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
            For Each Link In ElementCol                                                     
              If Link.innerHTML = "Connexion" Then                                            
                Link.Click                                                                      
                Exit For                                                                    
              End If                                                                          
            Next Link
```

But this code is not working anymore.

Even if I'm not using VBA, if I'm loading the webpage with Internet Explorer, I can't interact with the "Connexion" button with my mouse neither. (it seems that internet explorer is not able to see and interact with javascript after the last update)

Comment: You've tagged this as a [tag:java] question, but I'm not seeing this. Please clarify how the question relates Java programming. It mentions JavaScript in some HTML, and so this may have relevance, but I don't see true Java relevance. No sense attracting the wrong people, those who follow the Java tag, to the question.

Comment: I've remove the java tag. 
Sorry for that mistake but since the problem was not here before the update I had the feeling the problem could be trigger by Java version or javascript or something like that. And that maybe Java Programmer could have an answer as well.
I'm trying to find a solution to force the javascript to be run direct through VBA code but I think the page is charging with some errors with IE.

Comment: Again, I don't see how Java or change in Java version has anything to do with this. Yes, JavaScript may relate, but that is a completely different language from Java other the unfortunate naming similarity.

Comment: I'm guessing that you would want to get a handle on the HTML button element held by the DOM tree, who knows, perhaps something like `Document.getElementsByTagName("button")`, or better, `Document.getElementById(...)` if you know the id in order to interact with it, perhaps by id or tag name, but again, this does not involve Java code. But having said that, I know Java much better than HTML or JavaScript and so am not equipped to fully answer.

Comment: Would help to show more of your code (eg how you got to `Link`) and descibe exactly what you mean by "not working"  Do you get an error?  If Yes what error is it?

Comment: The executed js is `apex.submit({request:'LOGIN'})` so you could try running that using something like `execScript`  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa741364(v=vs.85)

Comment: I've add the full code to give you an idea how I find "Link"
Like I said previously, the code was working well before the last update but now, Internet Explorer can not interact with the connexion button even if I'm trying to click manually with my mouse. (the problem do not exist with Edge but I cant run my VBA automatisation with Edge).
I will take a look about the execScript solution.

Comment: It's possible the updated page is no longer compatible with IE - if that's the case then you may be out of luck 

Comment: Even Microsoft [ended support for Internet Explorer in June 2022](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/internet-explorer-help-23360e49-9cd3-4dda-ba52-705336cc0de2#:~:text=Support%20for%20Internet%20Explorer%2011%20ended%20on%20June%2015%2C%202022.). Perhaps it's time for your code to join the rest of the world.

Comment: Yes but some companies don't allow the installation of external stuff like Selenium and even if Microsoft stopped support for IE in 2022 they let people the opportunity of using it until 2029. After working more on the problem, I think it's a JavaScript /JQuery version problem which is causing some issue (synthase and undefined variable) with the page loading and interacting.